Can someone tell me why the following LINQ query fails to return expected data/incorrectly compares dates?
Hi I have the following logic:
   var time1 = new DateTime(2024,08,25)
   var time2 = new DateTime(2024,09,02)

if a table contained a object (we'll call it 'A') with properties:
Start = DateTime(2024,08,25)
End = DateTime(2024,08,25)

the following logic does not return 'A' even though it should.
_repo.Get().Where(x => x.Start.CompareTo(time2) <= 0 && time1.CompareTo(x.End) <= 0

But if i do
var compareResult = A.Start.CompareTo(time2) <= 0 && time1.CompareTo(A.End) <= 0

it returns true?
can someone please explain why?

What's the error you are getting?

Perhaps the reason is in different DateTimeKind of objects returning with _repo.Get() and variable time1. Try define time1 like this var time1 = new DateTime(2024, 08, 25, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

These are equivalent. I am pretty sure there is something in your "table" that you don't expect. Like seconds in the dates or they aren't of DateTime type and compare is used not the one you expect. P S yes Olegs idea re Kind is also good

the dates in the repo do not contain time (ie. they are set to 00:00:00)
